# How do I specify port binding for a .Net Core 3.1 API running in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a .Net 3.1 API running as a Docker container (WSL2+ Linux Containers) on Windows 10. I am unable to access the API on any other ports except 5000 :

When i run the container as

```
docker run -d -p 8060:7110 golide/payapi:0.1.0
```

and try a GET in Postman to http://localhost:7110/weatherforecast I get "Unable to Connect" exception.
But when i run the container as

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 golide/payapi:0.1.0
```

and try a GET in Postman to http://localhost:5000/weatherforecast I get the API response.

What am I missing regarding how Kestrel port binding works ?

My Dockerfile looks as follows :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PaymentsAPI.dll"]
```

What additional configuration should I do (if any) in order to access the API on any other port ?

Answer (score 2):

For the port (`-p`) option of `docker run`, the format looks like `<host-port>:<container-port>`. Since you used a value of `8060:7110` and attempted to access `localhost:7110` on the host, you're targeting the wrong port. You should be targeting `8060` from the host, or swap the position of the ports if that's what you need.

Then you'd also want to have `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:<container-port>` set in your Dockerfile as well.